# How to detect whether device has a vibrator?

Tags: javascript, html, vibration

With `navigator.vibrate` one can make smartphones and tablets vibrate. However, the function is also available on desktop browsers, so its presence is not useful to detect whether a vibration motor is actually available.

Of course, I could check if the device is running a mobile OS for a decent approximation, but is there a proper way to detect whether vibration is actually available?

Reason: I'm using the vibration in a game, and include an on/off button for it. It makes no sense to show this button on a desktop PC.

Comment: @ZougenMoriver given that that's a conclusive reply you should write an answer with the relevant quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it sounds like you can't:

> So apparently this is intentional, to avoid exposing accessibility
>   settings (which are seen as sensitive), to allow UAs to offer a
>   fallback, and potentially as a barrier to fingerprinting too.

*From http://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/1217*

[The spec itself](http://dev.w3.org/2009/dap/vibration/#h2_vibration-interface) says:

> If pattern is an empty list, or if the device is unable to vibrate,
>   then return true and terminate these steps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems impossible to detect if the device would actually vibrate somehow, so when I came to a similar problem I just used a fallback to sound if the OS seems not to be mobile device:

```
var navigatorTest = (function(ua){
  return function(){
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
      if(ua.indexOf(arguments[i]) >= 0)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  };
})(navigator.userAgent);

var bleep = ((
  (navigatorTest("iPad", "iPod", "iPhone", "Android") || !navigatorTest("Macintosh", "Windows", "X11", "Linux"))
  && (navigator.vibrate || navigator.webkitVibrate || navigator.mozVibrate || navigator.msVibrate)
) || (
  function(ctx){
    return function(len){
        var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
        osc.connect(ctx.destination);
        osc.start();
        setTimeout(function(){
            osc.stop();
        }, len);
    };
  }
)(
  window.AudioContext ? new AudioContext() : new webkitAudioContext()
)).bind(navigator, 300);  // Vibration/bleep time
```

Although it is not what you mean (not a feature detection) it gives a fair fallback.